# Miscalculation in Python code in Flask program

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using HTML input (text and buttons) to generate values for the following page in my Flask program:

```
@app.route('/sale/add', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_sale():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comp = 150
        pen = 0
        bonus = 0
        base = 0
        if request.form['stm'] == 1:
            if request.form['call'] == 'yes':
                comp += 150
                if request.form['ryg'] == 0:
                    pen += 150
            elif request.form['call'] == 'no':
                comp += 100
                if request.form['ryg'] == 0:
                    pen += 150
        else:
            comp = 150
            pen = 0
        if request.form['fee'] == 0:
            pen += 50
        if request.form['level'] >= 1:
            base += 400
```

I am asking for help with the Python code,because no matter what values are input through the HTML form, the variable `comp` always comes out as `150` and `base` always comes out as `400`. It is not a problem with the HTML tables, because the values are entered into the database properly. It is only the Python variables that I am having trouble with.

For example,

`request.form['call']` is entered into the database as `'yes'` and `request.form['stm']` is entered as `1` but the variable `comp` is still calculated as `150` (instead of `300`)

`request.form['level']` is entered as `0` but the variable `base` is still calculated as `400` (instead of `0`)

I am not including the HTML or SQL code here because I don't think that is what is affecting the outcome, but if it is helpful, I can edit and add it in.

Sample DB entry:
`(ID,name,date,date2,call,stm,ryg,fee,bonus,base,compPay,penalty,bonusPay,basePay)`
`(7, u'fj', u'2015-05-27', None, u'yes', 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 150.0, 0.0, 0.0, 400.0)`

Comment: Clearly this means that it is not hitting the block of the `request.form['stm'] == 1` conditional, thus I'd say that's not `== 1`. My guess? It's a string, not a number.

Comment: (7, u'fj', u'jf', u'2015-05-27', None, u'cold', 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 150.0, 0.0, 0.0, 400.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `__getitem__` returns the values as strings, but you are comparing them to numbers.  In Python 3 this would helpfully have thrown a `TypeError`, but Python 2 lets you get away with this.  The solution is to either:

- Compare the value with a string: `request.form['stm'] == "1"
- Convert the value to a number: `request.form.get('stm', type=int) == 1`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was confused because, as you can see from the edit, they are stored in the database as int not strings. But this solved it.

Comment: The database coerces types when it can